# Dockerfile tar error: tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive

Tags: dockerfile, find, tar

I'm trying to use a find and tar ubuntu commands to select all the csproj files in the project (in an elegant way) so that i can run dotnet restore in a layer in a Docker file (separately than building the solution).

I've read these solutions here and am trying to get them to work.

https://andrewlock.net/optimising-asp-net-core-apps-in-docker-avoiding-manually-copying-csproj-files-part-2/

However, I keep getting an error using the first approach:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

i can't understand why this is happening - the find command doesn't appear to be finding any files when run in the dockerfile.  When i run the find command locally on my disk, it is finding the csproj files as expected. See here:

[image: find files]

https://github.com/ossentoo/dockerbuildtest/runs/3850694961?check_suite_focus=true

Can anyone see what the problem is?  Perhaps you can send me a pull request?

See here for my sample.

https://github.com/ossentoo/dockerbuildtest

thanks

Comment: How do your project files end up in the container? I didn't see any COPY, ADD or volume mounts that could have imported them.

Comment: I can see that a github pipeline has been set up. The configuration is in the build.yml file within github workflows. hence copy/add or volume mounts is not required.

Would be interesting to see the github runner console logs as to whether it could create the tars directory in the root directory and then just list all the files it can fine within the github project using the below

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base

RUN mkdir -p /tars
RUN find . -name *.csproj

Comment: so, this is just a sample dockerfile. The ultimate aim is to have a tar -xvf csprojFiles.tar to untar the files in the right structure and then run dotnet restore.  I will update in the sample so that you can see what i mean.  However, the point of the question is how to resolve the find command issue first - because the tar file isn't being created.

Comment: i've updated the dockerfile to show what i'd like to achieve. https://github.com/ossentoo/dockerbuildtest/blob/main/Dockerfile.  have a look at the action: https://github.com/ossentoo/dockerbuildtest/runs/3850694961?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: Also remember that if `*` is unquoted it's parsed by shell before being passed to `find`.

Comment: thanks - but that doesn't appear to make any difference:                                            Step 3/7 : RUN find . -name '*.csproj' | xargs tar cvf /tars/csprojFiles.tar
 ---> Running in 4c0eeec64906
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: @ossentoo: that clearly means there are no `*.csproj` files in your Docker image. Do you realize that `RUN` are inside *inside* your image, not on your host?

Comment: ok - i think i get it now. Are you saying i need to copy the csproj files first?  In fact, looks like i should copy all files first, create a tar, then create an image from which i can copy the tar file.  Understood. let me try that.

Comment: Arkadiusz, please post an answer and I mark it as correct.  it looks like that was the problem (i wasn't copying the files into docker image first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That clearly means there are no *.csproj files in your Docker
image. The problem is that `RUN` commands are run inside inside your
image, not on your host so you have to add *.csproj to your image
first.

Comment: thanks Arkadiusz.  very helpful and helped me get to the bottom of the problem.  Yes, i was confusing file on the host with files in the image